# LaunchScreen.storyboard appearing differently on devices than in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter, storyboard

I am attempting to customize the default LaunchScreen.storyboard of my Flutter app. I simply have a red background on the default `View`, and I added an `Image View` as a child of it. This `Image View` is centered on the screen and renders an image that I have added to "Assets.xcassets" with all 3 sizes. Below is a preview of what my Xcode displays:

[image: Xcode]

However, this storyboard renders differently on devices than it appears in Xcode. For example, it appears slightly off-centered on iPhone 12, and it is scaled up too high for iPhone 6s and is way off-centered. See below for screenshots:

[image: iPhone 12]

[image: iPhone 6]

As you can see, the storyboard renders differently on the two devices. How can I make the storyboard appear the same on both devices as it does in Xcode? Any help is appreciated. If I used any incorrect terminology or need to provide additional details, please let me know as I have minimal experience using Xcode.

Comment: click on `imageview` remove all constraint than see storyboard editor has `align` left side to `add new constraint` click on than and set centre vertical & horizontal than click on `add new constraint` set `width` 100 & `height` 100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the storyboard screenshot attached, it looks like there are no constraints added to the `UIImageView`.

You should add `top`, `leading`, `bottom` & `trailing` constraints to superview with 0 spacing to achieve what you want.

**UPDATE**

Above is applicable to the case when you have a small size image like 100x100 or similar that can easily fit on all screen sizes. In the comments, we see that image is way too big and we want to keep it in center while occupying 50% of screen width.

Remove the `leading` and `trailing` constraints, select the imageView and it's superview - add equal widths constraint with a multiplier of **0.5**, this will make sure that imageView will always occupy **50%** of the superview's width.

Also add horizontally center constraint on the imageView. Make sure imageView Content Mode is set to **Aspect Fit**.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the problem of the icon not being centered! However, I now am not able to make the icon smaller. I tried adjusting the constraints to do so, but it appears full-width on all devices regardless of what it shows in Xcode. Is there a way to fix that as well?

Comment: You can set Content Mode for ImageView to `Center` .

Comment: That seemed to made the image scale way up, and I am unable to adjust the size anymore. This screenshot is the result: [https://imgur.com/a/BqWAnp8](https://imgur.com/a/BqWAnp8). Any other ideas? Thanks again for your insight.

Comment: To clarify what I am trying to achieve, I would like the image to be proportionally scaled to the size of the screen (~50% of the entire width). Would scaling the size actual image file itself down fix the problem?

Comment: @Iamaregistereduser See the **UPDATE** to my answer.